# Which hook to use to give a user a role after purchasing something in Commerce 2?

Tags: 8, commerce

I made a site that sells services in Commerce 2.  I want to hide access to the "Orders" and "Payment info" pages until a user purchases the first product.

To do this, I created a role, **Paid**, for users who have purchased something.  This role has permission to view orders and so forth.

Which hook should I use to give the user the **Paid** role after making a purchase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Drupal 8 Commerce is using [Event dispatcher](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/event_dispatcher.html) instead of hooks.

In this case, you should subscribe into the event named **commerce_order.order.assign**, the hook invoked then a order is assigned to a user. In this moment you can code to grant the role to the user. You can see an example of how commerce_log submodule from commerce used this event [here](https://github.com/drupalcommerce/commerce/blob/8.x-2.x/modules/log/src/EventSubscriber/OrderEventSubscriber.php).

If you need, you have [this tutorial](https://www.chapterthree.com/blog/how-to-register-event-subscriber-drupal8) which tells you how to subscribe to a event from event dispatcher.

Comment: Thanks, this also enabled me to find some Commerce 2 documentation on this: https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/developer-guide/orders/react-to-workflow-transitions